# Ajax validation required when updating user-information yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

So i reached the Ajax validation part. First i want to say that i read the answers of similar question but it did not helped me.
On registration form validation works good(when i try to register user with existing name it shows me error message), but when i am in the users profile and try to update his name with existing one nothing happens(no error shown).

My model UpdateForm.php rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email', 'password', 'username'], 'required'],
            [['email', 'password', 'username'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['image'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['email', 'email'],
            [[ 'email', 'username'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }
```

My UserController action:

```
public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Will appreciate every advice!

Comment: you are using same model and form for both create and update

Comment: Thank you! I took a look at my actionRegister and now understood it :)

Answer (score 0):

configure yii_logger db in your machine (you can find it Yii2 docs).

then run

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(log_time, '%Y-%m-%d') log_date, y.*  FROM yii_logger y where level = 1 order by log_time desc limit 20;
```

you may see error backtrace if your code is breaking somewhere.